# Clarity on a property of infimum and supremum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration

I came across this property while studying material on Reimann Integral, i.e when is a function integrable. (When $inf{U} = sup{L}$, where U and L are the upper and lower bound of sums).

For a set S, corresponding to any $\epsilon_1>0$, $\exists$ an element of the set S (say $X_i$), such that

$X_i$ < $inf{S}$ + $\epsilon_1$

Similarly,

$X_j$ > $sup{S}$ - $\epsilon_2$

Here, $infS$ is the greatest lower bound of the set, so I can see how adding some constant to this lower bound can exceed some other element of the set. But how can I realize that this will be true for all the elements of the set. Also, I don't understand the utility of this result.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: The supremum and infimum are used, for example, to construct $\sqrt{2}$. Also, you can use this property of infimum, for example, to show that a decreasing sequence with a lower bound converges to its infimum (analogous to the supremum).

Comment: Consider the set S = {3,4,5}. Here there are infinite lower bounds. The greatest of all lower bounds is 3 and hence $inf{S}$ is 3. 
Now using above definition, if I take $\epsilon = 1/2$, there won't be any $X_i$ such that $X_i < 3 + 1/2$.
Also acc. to your comment, if I take x as 4, then I don't find any such y such that $infS<y<x$

Comment: I will rewrite my comment because I made a typo. The property $X_i<\inf S+\epsilon_1$ means that if $\inf S<x$ you always can find $y \in S$ such that $\inf S \leq y<x$; in another words, every element grather than $\inf S$ cannot be a lower bound to $S$ or, equivalently, $\inf S$ is the greatest lower bound of $S$. For the $\sup S$ the idea is similar. If $S = \{3,4,5\}$ and you take $\epsilon = 1/2$, then $S \ni 3 < 3 + 1/2$ and $S \ni 3 < 4$. If $\inf S \in S$ (what is your case), it must be considered in the definition as any element of $S$.

Comment: Ah, okay. I think I understand now. 
So, let's say S is the set of all real numbers in [1,2], then $infS$ being 1 is also part of S. So for the inequality $X_i<infS+\epsilon$, no maater how small $\epsilon$ I take, $X_i=1\in S$ will always satisfy the condition.
Whereas, if S is set of all real numbers in (1,2), here $infS$ is 1 but not part of S. Then again no matter how small $\epsilon$ I take, say h, the condition $X_i<1+h$ will satisfy for $X_i = 1+h/2 \in S$ and many more such $X_i$.
Let me know if there is any mistake in my understanding. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: You are right. If a set is closed, then $\inf$ and $\sup$ are in the set, more specifically, $\inf = \min$ and $\sup = \max$ so that in this cases is trivial to find them.